# How to toggle selection of an option in a multi-select with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have a standard `select multiple` HTML Input field, for example:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="5" id="mysel" name="countries"> 
    <option value="2">Afghanistan</option> 
    <option value="4">Aland</option> 
</select>
```

As this is a multi-select, to select more than one value you have to hold the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key and select any further elements. However what I want to achieve is, that:

1. Clicking an UNSELECTED option SELECTs it
2. Clicking a SELECTED option UNSELECTS it.

The idea is to avoid having to press the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key and change the usage semantics of this input field. Elements should only be selectable and un-selectable by clicking (ie. toggling of the select status).

I have not yet been able to implement this. The pseudo-code should look something like this.

1. Catch a Click event.
2. Check if the element that was clicked was unselected, then select it
3. Or if the element that was clicked was selected, then unselect it.

How should I implement this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may use the following snippet to achieve your desired effect

```
$("select[multiple] option").mousedown(function(){
   var $self = $(this);

   if ($self.prop("selected"))
          $self.prop("selected", false);
   else
       $self.prop("selected", true);

   return false;
});
```

In older versions of jQuery, where `prop()` was not available:

```
$("select[multiple] option").mousedown(function(){
   var $self = $(this);

   if ($self.attr("selected"))
          $self.attr("selected", "");
   else
       $self.attr("selected", "selected");

   return false;
});
```

Comment: Hello TB, Ohh, thanks a Million Times!!!! Great! This is what I wanted to achieve! Thanks so much!!

Comment: It would be more concise to do `$self.prop('selected', !$self.prop('selected'));`.

Comment: @nilskp also consider ```$self.prop('selected', function(i,old){!old});```

Comment: `this.selected = !this.selected` is much shorter and faster.

Answer (score 4):

You're right in wanting to change the default behaviour of select multiple input fields. They tend to contribute negatively towards user experience as the purpose is not clearly conveyed and users' may not understand how to use them correctly.

Re-purposing a multi-select box isn't right either. If you are considering using select multiple, then you might want to refactor your design. Perhaps you can use checkboxes instead?

Here's an article on the topic: http://www.ryancramer.com/journal/entries/select_multiple/

Comment: Hello 2020vert. Thanks for your fast answer. Thats quite funny, the articale you pointed out I have already read (in part), as I stumpled upon this article already by searching for a solution for my problem. It would be great to find a solution as asked with the "toggling" of the status. I thinks this should somehow be possible but sadly theres no simple way to query for the select/unselect status... thanks

Answer (score 4):

I just tried this solution and the selected answer did not work for Jquery 1.9.1

The answer by Oscar looked much better but it mixed properties with attributes and doesnt work if you select, de-select then try to select again as it puts the select into an unusable state

I have found the correct answer for me was the following

```
$("select[multiple] option").mousedown(function () {
       if ($(this).prop("selected"))
           $(this).prop("selected", false);
       else
           $(this).prop("selected", true);
       return false;    });
```

I hope this helps others ;)

Comment: It looks like the accepted answer got ninja-edited to copy your answer, but I guess I don't know what it was before.

Comment: At least someone liked my solution enough to copy i guess ;) pity about the history of the question and any future users stuck on pre 1.9.1 jQuery, Thx for noticing @PrinceTyke

Answer (score 2):

Another variant without JQuery:

```
var multiSelect = {};

function init() {      
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i].multiple) {
      var n = s[i].name;
      multiSelect[n] = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < s[i].options.length; j++) {
        multiSelect[n][j] = s[i].options[j].selected;
      }
      s[i].onclick = changeMultiSelect;
    }
  }
}

function changeMultiSelect() {
  var n = this.name;
  for (var i=0; i < this.options.length; i++) {
    if (this.options[i].selected) {
      multiSelect[n][i] = !multiSelect[n][i];
    }
    this.options[i].selected = multiSelect[n][i];
  }
}

window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably some fix coming with the new jQuery versions:

```
$("select[multiple] option").mousedown(function(){
    var $self = $(this);

    if ($self.attr("selected")){
        $self.removeAttr("selected");
    } else {
        $self.attr("selected", "selected");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript (without jquery):

```
var select = document.getElementById('mysel');
select.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    var opt = e.target;
    if (opt.selected){
        opt.removeAttribute('selected');
        opt.selected = false;
    } else {
        opt.setAttribute('selected', '');
        opt.selected = true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I see most of the answers above are binding the event with the option instead of the select. If my select has 1000 options, then it will bind 1000 events, will it affect the performance?

Because of this I also decide not to bind my event in the option.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery 1.9.1 the javascript code is:

```
   $("select[multiple] option").mousedown(function () {
       var $self = $(this);
       if ($self.prop("selected"))
           $self.removeAttr("selected");
       else
           $self.attr("selected", "selected");
       return false;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here to solve the same issue I had. I modified the solution of user1106925 as it was not working (clicking on the selection was immediately unselecting it).
My solution:

```
onclick = "this.selected ? this.selected = !this.selected;"
```