# Select Multiple 2nd click deselect

Tags: jquery, html, multiple-select

Is it possible to make it where when an option in select multiple is selected you can click again to deselect it? If so how, I am having trouble finding information on it through searching.

Edit: I need to support chrome, safari, firefox, and IE.

Comment: you mean just as it does when you CTRL+click it again?

Comment: Yes, I need it to deselect the option if a selected option is clicked again

Comment: There's an answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585863/how-can-i-make-an-html-multiple-select-act-like-the-control-button-is-held-down

Comment: my apologies, i did not get that from the question, but @Cᴏʀʏ's answer is what you're looking for

Comment: @Cory, the solution there does not work for me. The last solution on that page works in chrome, but not IE

Comment: @connormoore, Please list the browsers you need the solution to support in your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to deselect a particular item in a multiselect, `CTRL+click` it again

Comment: I know this, but is there a way around this. I am building an application and that may not be a known fact for the users. I need the functionality to be you click an option, it selects, you click that same option again, it deselects