# Why do <select multiple> boxes scroll to the top with preventDefault in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, preventdefault

Every time I add an event listner that somehow does a `preventDefault` on a change to the select-box, it scrolls to the top.

For a minimal example, see below:

```js
document.getElementById('foo').onmousedown = function(e) {
  e.target.parentElement.focus();
  e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<select multiple size="5" id="foo">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
</select>
```

Steps to reproduce this weird behaviour is:

1. Click on option `2`
2. Scroll down a bit
3. Click on any option-element

Your view should now have scrolled up to have option `2` at the very top.

This seems bizarre behaviour to me, which is really annoying.

Follow-up question to this: how can I stop this from happening? I'm trying to make a script that makes `select multiple` boxes behave as if the ctrl-key is always pressed (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48217702/1256925) but that code doesn't work when the `size` is greater than the amount of options listed.

*EDIT*: I've tested it in MS Edge (I don't have Firefox on this PC), and it seems to handle this correctly, so this might be a Chrome-only bug. If so, my follow-up question remains: how do I prevent Chrome from doing this? (Also, could someone update me on whether this happens in FF as well?)

Comment: I've made a workaround by adding a wrapper-div that has `overflow-y: auto; border: 1px solid darkgrey;` and then setting `overflow: visible; border: none;` on the select itself, but of course that is a really hacky fix (hence why I'm posting this workaround in the comments and not as a self-answer). I'm still looking for a good fix for this problem.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to control the behavior of native elements like multi-select boxes. BTW, Safari has the bug, too, but FF doesn't. So it's probably a WebKit issue.

Comment: it doesn't actually scroll to the top, it scrolls to the item you selected the first time. Even if it's no longer selected. So if you select 4, 2, unselect 4, then select 10, it scrolls to 4. Very weird that it remembers that.

Comment: It's hard to imagine how a bug like that could happen, it seems like it would have to be something you try hard to do.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think this is a duplicate at all. I'm not asking for a way to make select-elements behave as if ctrl is pressed, I'm trying to ask for a general way to stop the box from scrolling to the first-selected element when using preventDefault.

Comment: That's exactly the problem reported in the duplicate: "It works fine with one exception: any time something is selected/deselected that is not at the top of the list (where you have to scroll to see it) then it pops back up to the top after you select it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this workaround (it works atleast in Chrome):

```js
document.getElementById('foo').onmousedown = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var st = this.scrollTop;
  e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;
  setTimeout(() => this.scrollTop = st, 0);
  this.focus();
}

document.getElementById('foo').onmousemove= function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<select multiple size="5" id="foo">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Btw I see that it was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543862/selecting-multiple-from-an-html-select-element-without-using-ctrl-key#27056015) so it should be marked as duplicate..