# <select multiple> with no scrolling and no ctrl click required and work on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

My issue is very similar to that described and 'answered' here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48218562/8656459

I would like to be able to click multiple elements without CTRL being required and also without it scrolling up, but it seems like Chrome Mobile (android) still sees the mouse down (although no mice are involved), and then the options do not appear due to the preventDefaults, such as this:
[image: Select default operation on Chrome Android]

What is the best way to go about fixing it?

here is the jsfiddle if it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/95ntdrjc/

No JQuery please.

```js
const selectElem = document.querySelector('select');
selectElem.onmousedown = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const st = this.scrollTop;
  e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;
  setTimeout(() => this.scrollTop = st, 0);
  this.focus();
};

selectElem.onmousemove = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a very simple fix!

```
selectElem.ontouchstart = function() {selectElem.onmousedown = null;};
```

On touchStart, these events are fired:

- touchstart
- Zero or more touchmove events, depending on movement of the finger(s)
- touchend
- mousemove
- mousedown
- mouseup
- click

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent#Event_order

This nullifies what occurs during the mousedown process, so mobile can continue as normal, whilst desktop has the version which doesn't scroll and doesn't require CTRL to select multiple.