# Multiple select list deselects all selections when moving mouse while clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking at making multiple select lists on my application a little more user friendly by not requiring the user to hold the control key to select multiple options, by using the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096259/html-select-multiple-input-field-how-to-select-deselect-toggle-a-value-with).

It works great, except I noticed if you even slightly move the mouse while clicking options, it deselects all the previously selected options.

Is there a way to correct this behavior or is it something I will just have to live with?

Example:

```js
$('select[multiple] option').mousedown(function() {
  $(this).prop('selected', !$(this).prop('selected'));
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
  <option>D</option>
  <option>E</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, just an FYI, but you can shorten and speed up your code if you do `this.selected = !this.selected`. jQuery's `.prop()` isn't really needed here.

Comment: I don't see the behavior you describe in Firefox. What browser does this?

Comment: I see what you mean. If the user clicks the mouse and drags out of the select element it is deselecting everything. I think you might have to live with that.

Comment: @squint Thanks for that FYI. I will use that instead. As for not seeing the behavior, try selecting the elements quickly, its definitely quirky. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Ah, I see it does it in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add in a second event handler to listen for the `mousemove` event, you can tell it to ignore the default action. This prevents the selected options dropping off, but keeps your original functionality

```js
$('select[multiple] option').on('mousedown', function(event) {
    this.selected = !this.selected;
    return false;
});

// Prevent the mousemove from having any effect on the select  box
$('select[multiple] option').on('mousemove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" size="5">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Coconut</option>
  <option>Date</option>
  <option>Elderberry</option>
</select>
```